# Is it possible to add a variable to an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm really frustrated with rails because of a ton of little problems like this.

I have a model called `timelines`. In it is a datetime column but the javascript that I'm passing the data too is expecting a date only. So I want to add a new string to my model object before passing it to the view. This seems impossible.

First I gather the data from the database and put it into an instance variable:

```
@timeline = Timeline.where(token: params[:token]).first
```

Then I try to add on to that variable like this:

```
@timeline.birthday = "1/1/2000"
```

I get an error that says:

`undefined method birthday= for #<Timeline:0x00000105add0d0>`

I'm guessing it's saying this because `birthday` is not a column in my database. I know it's not, and I don't care that it's not in my database. I just want to add onto my variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add accessor methods to be able to get/set birthday. It won't be persisted, though.

```
class Timeline
  attr_accessor :birthday
end
```

### Alternative solution

The underlying problem you seem to be having ("javascript expects something else") can be solved in a couple of ways. [Presenter](http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2014/decorators-presenters-delegators-rails/) pattern, for example. Or use ActiveModel Serializers.

This will allow you to keep the model as is, and, upon rendering, transform data to format expected by client-side.

Comment: When you say it doesn't persist, I think it doesn't persist for more than 1ms. I've added that into my model and now I don't get the error, but when I do this I don't see the variable set at all: 
@timeline.birthday = "1/1/2000"
puts YAML::dump(@timeline)

Comment: Well, it is there. Try `puts @timeline.birthday`

Comment: Ok `puts @timeline.birthday` works. However why isn't it in the object when I examine it? The next thing I need to do is convert this variable to json and it's not seeing that added variable when I do.

Comment: Well, it's a question to how YAML::dump is implemented. Take a look at ActiveModel Serializers, this is the way to go here, I think

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the original datetime column to date by using:

```
your_column_name.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

Comment: Does he? "I have a model called timelines. In it is a datetime column..."

Comment: I think that was after he had trouble with his original approach due to datetime formatting and tried to add the "birthday" attribute to the model.

Comment: That's nice. For me, this is a hobby :-)